# can we add ahah element into form using ahah?

Tags: ajax

I am using ahah for drupal 6.
Now there is scenario in which I need to add ahah field into a form.

There is one form and in that form, there is one ahah field on submit button.

Now when user clicks on that ahah button, I want to add another ahah field with textbox and button. The button which we add through ahah should have ahah for adding more content.

is it possible to add ahah submit button using ahah submit button ?